# How to design ADF pipeline to split a container data into multiple containers of cosmos database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb

I want to create a ADF pipeline to move source container(cosmos DB) data into multiple target containers(cosmos DB) based on filter conditions (example below). can you please help me with the activities order and their expression, variables or parameters I need to use. your help is much appreciated, thanks

```
|Source  | target  | Filter condition                  |
|------  |-------- | ----------------                  |                  
| Ingest | Sales   | where c.source in ('salesOrderS4')|
| Ingest | Plan    | where c.source in ('planning')    |
| Ingest | Logic   | where c.source in ('logisticsASN')|
```

Sample source container data :

```
[
    {
        "id": "5961fc41-4508144870-90",
        "source": "logisticsASN",
        "blobTriggerStartTime": "2021-12-22T11:45:03.999Z",
        "processEndTime": "2021-12-22T11:45:09.624Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "1a0862e2-4301527947-20",
        "source": "planning",
        "blobTriggerStartTime": "2022-12-09T11:46:35.604Z",
        "processEndTime": "2022-12-09T11:46:44.542Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "bad34955-481d-60",
        "source": "salesOrderS4",
        "blobTriggerStartTime": "2022-06-01T00:23:23.090Z",
        "processEndTime": "2022-06-01T00:23:27.965Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide your sample input data and expected output data in target containers?

Comment: Please edit to provide all relevant detail. As written, this is only a requirement, with expectation that the Community provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks for reminding @RakeshGovindula - have provided sample input data. each source type item from sample data need to be loaded into respective target containers

Answer (score 1):

To do split the source container data, into the target containers on a filter condition, you should have the list of target containers and strings that you want to check in condition.

So, I have taken a sample cosmos source data like below. Here my `target` column is same as your `source` column.

```
[
{
"id": "24",
"target": "Sales",
},
{
"id": "26",
"target": "Plan",
},
{
"id": "16",
"target": "logic",
}
]
```

I took the containers list and filter strings list in a csv file for the easy comparison.

[image]

Use this in a lookup activity and give the lookup output array to a Foreach(check the sequential).

Inside ForEach, give the source cosmos db dataset and use the below query in query option.

```
select * from c where contains('@{item().filterstr}',c.target)
```

[image]

In sink, use dataset parameter for the cosmos db container name and give the `@item().target` for it like below.

[image]

Execute this and you can see the data copied to different containers.

[image]

**NOTE**: Copy activity won't create the target containers automatically. Make sure the required containers created before the pipeline run.